# How to disable check in codeclimate?

Tags: code-climate

Сan you please guide me on how to reduce the full test coverage threshold in the config file in the repository? I had 33% full coverage in some project, my edits reduced it to 0.2, and I would like to say to codeclimate that this is acceptable

I have my golang repo and .codeclimate.yml in root:

```
version: "2"         # required to adjust maintainability checks
checks:
  return-statements:
    enabled: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as pointed [here](https://github.com/codeclimate/test-reporter/issues/271#issuecomment-351166376) there is no configuration to modify that.

Extracted from the [docs](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/configuring-your-analysis#section-test-coverage)

> If the overall test coverage percentage of your repository will decrease (by 0.1% >or more) by merging the PR, Code Climate will send a failed status to Github.

If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to increase that threshold to lets say 0.5%, so for the case of your edits codeclimate doesn't raise a flag. If that's the case, then again, that's not configurable.

> Under your Repo -> Settings, you can enable or disable sending pass/fail statuses >on your total coverage.

Comment: many thanks for feedback. I was hoping that there are ways, perhaps not described enough in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/configuring-your-analysis) document. You can disable the `Enforce Diff Coverage` and `Enforce Totoal Coverage` checks in codeclimate so that these reports are not run for your commits.